# Open Dialog or Modal if AUTH_ERROR (401)

Tags: admin-on-rest

I would like to open a Dialog or Modal if I get a status 401 in AUTH_ERROR. What is the best way to implement this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to take the custom app route:

Follow the [documentation](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/CustomApp.html) to bootstrap your custom app.

Add a saga which should take the latest (`takeLatest` in redux-saga) [`FETCH_ERROR`](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/src/actions/fetchActions.js) action. This action has an `error` property. The saga should then dispatch (`put` in redux-saga) a custom action which will be used by a reducer you'll add.

This reducer should contain the data required for the modal: at least a boolean determining whether to show it or not.

Finally, update your custom app by adding it a custom redux connected component which will check if it has to show your modal.